# How to apply JBoss AOP on a Jersey implementation?

Tags: java, jboss, jersey, aop

I am trying to apply aspect oriented programming concepts on a Java server implementation. I created a project on Eclipse EE, and developed a simple REST API server via Jersey. Then, I searched for an aspect oriented programming framework that can be used standalone and found JBoss AOP.

I added all jars under `jboss-aop-2.1.8.GA/lib` to the class and build path. Then, I created a simple `TestInterceptor` class doing nothing but printing out a dumb text. Then under `WebContent/META-INF/` I put the following `jboss-aop.xml`

```
<aop>
    <bind pointcut="execution(* *->*(..))">
        <interceptor class="com.rest...TestInterceptor"/>
    </bind>
</aop>
```

Plus, I added the following to the run arguments:

```
-javaagent:/.../workspace/com.rest.aspect.todo/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jboss/jboss-aop.jar 
-Djboss.aop.path="/.../workspace/com.rest.aspect.todo/WebContent/META-INF/jboss-aop.xml"
```

However, project fails to compile and throws error (Check http://pastebin.com/TPM1e2pj). What would be missing or wrong in what I have done so far?

Comment: Have you done Load-time or compile-time instrumentation of your classes ?

Comment: I try to do compilte-time.